# O que acontece quando eu uso o comando "npm install npm@6" usando o npm 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Tenho npm 7.5 instalando e preciso usar a versão 6.0 para usar o modulo @angular/cli.
Queria saber o que acontece quando uso o comando "npm install npm@6" e como usar as duas versões do npm

Comment: A solução é usar o NVM (Node Version Manager).